# Reference ol li Numbering Elsewhere in Outline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am putting our organization Bylaws online.  I have build the CSS to manage the outline:

```
ol  {   
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: bylawcounter;    
    }
ol li   {   
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-size: 24px;    
        }
ol li:before    {   
                content: "Bylaw " counter(bylawcounter,upper-roman) " - ";
                counter-increment:bylawcounter; 
                }


ol ol   {
        list-style-type: none;
        counter-reset: sectioncounter;  
        }

ol ol li    {   
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-size: 20px;    
        }
ol ol li:before {
                content: "Section " counter(bylawcounter) "." counter(sectioncounter) " - ";
                counter-increment:sectioncounter;   
                }

li p    {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16;
        }
```

This part is working swimmingly.  The next thing I need is some items in the Bylaws reference others.  I would like to make the HTML do this referencing automatically, instead of hard coded, that way if the Bylaws are amended, the reference will be correct without changing it.  For example:

```
<ol>
    <li>Organization</li>
    <ol>
        <li id="name">Name
            <p>This organization shall be known as "ABC, Inc.".</p></li>
        <li>Other Names
            <p>This organization shall never be know by any name not specified in <a href="#name">Section 1.1</a>.</p></li>
    </ol>
</ol>
```

So instead of hard coding "Section 1.1", I want to reference the id "Name" and get the associated counters.  Is that possible in HTML or JS?

Comment: with html no, with js it's possible, by the way how did the above css work ? variables(called custom properties) are a recent feature in css and its syntax isn't the same as the above

Comment: I didn't really expect that HTML would, but I am hoping JS will without too much difficulty.

The CSS woks perfect for numbering.  My outline, of course, went deeper than what I show here, but the principle can be extrapolated.  I still want to add a hanging indention, but that shouldn't be too difficult.